# How to create files having date in the file name using big query export data statement

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using BIG QUERY EXPORT DATA statement to create files in cloud storage for an another team to extract for further reprocessing. I am using below statement, not pasting the select query as its huge.

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
uri='gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/Customer_Master_*.csv',
format='CSV',
overwrite=true,
header=true,
field_delimiter='|') AS    
SELECT
```

I see below files getting created in my cloud storage bucket

```
 radhika_sharma_ibm@cloudshell:~ (whr-asia-datalake-nonprod)$ gsutil ls gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/
    gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/
    gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/Customer_Master_000000000000.csv
    gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/Customer_Master_000000000001.csv
    gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/Customer_Master_000000000002.csv
```

I cannot remove the suffix part as BIG QUERY creates it, but I am wondering if I can create files with DATE in the file name for the other team to identify what date it is created for??
That is like

`Customer_Master_04022021_000000000000_.csv`

I need to have a date in my file. Any help or inputs please?

Is there a work around or I will have to go with a data flow here that is using a data flow job to extract data from table in a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the uri value as:
'gs://bucket/folder/your_filename-'||current_datetime()||'-*.csv'

Either Current_date() or current_datetime() can be used.

Thanks